# How to create a setup for a web application with Web Platform Installer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, installation, web-platform-installer

I have a large Web Application ( ErPwith 11 subsystem) and I want tocreate a setup for itwith Microsoft WebPI.

Currently We send our application for customers once a week (for weekly updates).

We usefollowing tools in this application, So How to create a setup for out project toconfigure it in client IIS automatically

- List item
- .netFramework 3.5
- SQL server 2008
- Asp.net
- C#
- NHibernate
- Log4net
- castleProxy
- SQL Server Reporting Services (RDL)
- Visual Studio Client Reports (RDLC)
- Javascript
- JQuery

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you want to create a Web Deploy package of your application and a custom Web PI feed that will include this package into Web PI.

Here is a reference on how to build a Web Application package. You will be able to automate this step using Web Deploy command line:

- [Reference for the Web Application Package](http://learn.iis.net/)

One more reference is to a blog that has a sample feed that will include your application to Web PI through a cusotm feed. You will be able to automate this step by creating a custom feed and then just replacing the hash in the feed whenever a new package becomes available:

- [Web PI Extensibility: Custom Feeds – Installing Custom Applications](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-applications.aspx)